# Avoid using new JavaScript features not available in your target Node.js version. next.config.js will not be parsed by Webpack, Babel or TypeScript

Tags: next.js

Will this impact the features that we are going to use in React with JavaScript while using Next.js?

Expecting the answer that could manage my context with the use of features from Javascript
It is Important note that can seek the developers to use the details of all docs.